# How to apply transformation on the lookup target during lookup?

Tags: ssis

My source task has following columns read from csv file:
Sale_id, sale_date, order_no, sale_amt

This is followed by lookup task that looks into the sales sql table (having same column names) and the join is on order_no column.

The issue is that order_no data in sql sale table has value like 'ABC-12345', 'WXYZ-32111' (there are couple of characters prepended to the order number).

Where as in the csv there is '12345' without any characters prepended.

Hence I cannot do a lookup as there is no direct match. Is there any way to remove the characters and the hyphen from sale sql table data (temporarily) for performing the lookup join.

Comment: Is the data type in the database for 12345 a string or a number?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem restatement

In your source, you have order numbers coming in that look like numbers. You need to be able to lookup against a source that has a text string prepended to an order number. We can assume the numeric part of the database's order number is unique.

### Setup

I created a simplified version of your table and populated it with data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.so_66446302;
CREATE TABLE dbo.so_66446302
(
    sales_id int
,   order_no varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.so_66446302
(sales_id, order_no)
VALUES
    (1,  'ABC-12345')
,   (2,  'WXYZ-32111')
,   (3,  'REALLY_LONG-654321');
```

A critical piece in using Lookup components is getting the data types to agree. I'm going to assume that the order number from the file is a DT_STR and not an integer.

By default, people pick a table in the Lookup component's Connection tab, `dbo.so_66446302` but if you check "Use results of a SQL query", you'll have what you're looking for.

Similar query to what Jatin shows below but I find "showing my work" along the way helps me debug when it goes sideways. In this query, that's why I have the intermediate cross apply steps.

```
SELECT
    S.*
,   D0.order_no_as_string_digits
FROM
    dbo.so_66446302 AS S
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            -- Length of the string less where we find the first dash
            LEN(S.order_no) - CHARINDEX('-', S.order_no, 1)
    )D(dash_location)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT RIGHT(S.order_no, D.dash_location) 
    )D0 (order_no_as_string_digits);
```

The results of that query are

```
sales_id    order_no             order_no_as_string_digits
1           ABC-12345            12345
2           WXYZ-32111           32111
3           REALLY_LONG-654321   654321
```

Now you can match the derived order number in the database to the one in your file by dragging the columns together. Check any/all columns that you need to retrieve from the database and send the data to the intended destination.

Comment: The lookup data (sql table) has got the hyphen. The source data (flat file) has got just number. So the derived column won't help me unless you mean I should add the hyphen to the flat file data? The question I ask was how to remove hyphen from sql table during look up.

Comment: Ahhhhh, my apologies misread on that. Will it ever be that there is `FOO-12345` and `BAR-12345` or can we assume that the data after the hyphen is unique in the sql table?

Comment: Unique yes. I was wondering if using a sql in the lookup that strips off the part before hyphen and the hyphen is the solution. Or whether i must add ABC- to source data.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Data Flow Task** - Use Flat File Source to LookUp and OLE DB Source via SQL Command with the following to LookUp.

```
select Sale_id, sale_date, order_no, sale_amt,
substring(order_no,charindex('-',order_no,0),len(order_no)) as [key]
from sql sale table
```

Use [Key] for your look up transformation.
The functions should provide the numeric values you are looking for.